# How would I each through dynamic content and append something if a value = false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to iterate over some JSON that I have included in my file and everything seems to be working fine up until I want to add my icons into each stakebox icon div. Any idea what might be going wrong? I want to add one icon if the value of my JSON object === true and one if the value === false.

```
$.each(stakeBox, function (i, stakeBoxData) {
    var jsonDate = stakeBoxData.data_change_date;
    var winLoss = stakeBoxData.win;
    var points = stakeBoxData.amount_stakebox;
    var winLoss = stakeBoxData.win;
    var id = stakeBoxData.id;

    if (stakeBoxDay < jsonDate) {
        var self = $(this);
        console.log(this.win);
        $('.stakebox-container').append('\
        <div id="' + id + '" class="stakebox-message-container">\
            <div id="stakebox-icon"></div>\
            <div><h5 id="stakebox-game"></h5></div>\
            <div><h5 id="stakebox-points">' + points + '</h5></div>\
        </div>\
    ');

        if (this.win === true) {
            $('#stakebox-icon').append('<i class="far fa-smile face"></i>');
        } else {
            $('.stakebox-message-container').css('background', '#a20000');
            $('#stakebox-icon').append('<i class="far fa-frown face"></i>');
        };
        // console.log(i);
    } else {
        // console.log('nope');
    }
});
```

Here is some of the JSON for reference:

```
var stakeBox = [{
    id: "1",
    amount: "40.00",
    user_id: "1",
    amount_stakebox: "33",
    win: true,
    data_change_date: "20180229",
    username: "bkessler",
    game_id: "1380",
    team_id: "791",
    status: "1"
}, {
    id: "2",
    amount: "1.00",
    user_id: "1",
    amount_stakebox: "4124124",
    win: false,
    data_change_date: "20180429",
    username: "bkessler",
    game_id: "1380",
    team_id: "791",
    status: "1"
}];
```

Comment: JavaScript !== Java; [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Also, `id` should be unique, change `id="stakebox-icon"` to `class="stakebox-icon"`...you can see it working here https://jsfiddle.net/nnsh33dz/6/

Comment: @Hackerman that does solve one issue, it's going into each div now but the first one has 3 next has 2 and so on.

Comment: Can you explain yourself a little better...i didn't get the last part.